# How to configure a VisualizationViewer so users can move nodes with the mouse?

Tags: java, jung

I'm using Jung 2.0 for a while now, but I'm a bit confused with all the configuration code that is done in the various demos that ship with the package.

Could anyone tell me **how to configure a VisualizationViewer so that I can move the graph nodes around by clicking and draging them with the mouse?**

The code I have is below. It's a mix of the various demos I studied. But I can only pan and rotate the graph with it.

```
public class GrafoParticipacaoSocietaria extends JFrame {

    Graph<VerticeParticipacaoSocietaria, Integer> graph;
    VisualizationViewer<String, String> vv;
    Layout<VerticeParticipacaoSocietaria, Integer> layout;

    public GrafoParticipacaoSocietaria(Graph<VerticeParticipacaoSocietaria, Integer> grafoPart) {
        super("Participação Societária");

        graph = grafoPart;
        layout = new ISOMLayout(graph);

        final VisualizationModel visualizationModel = new DefaultVisualizationModel(layout);
        vv = new VisualizationViewer(visualizationModel);

        vv.getRenderer().getVertexLabelRenderer().setPosition(Renderer.VertexLabel.Position.CNTR);
        vv.getRenderContext().setVertexLabelTransformer(new ToStringLabeller<String>());
        vv.setForeground(Color.blue);
        getContentPane().add(vv);

        // this class will provide both label drawing and vertex shapes
        VertexLabelAsShapeRenderer<String, String> vlasr = new VertexLabelAsShapeRenderer<String, String>(
                vv.getRenderContext());

        vv.getRenderContext().setVertexShapeTransformer(vlasr);
        vv.getRenderContext().setVertexLabelRenderer(new DefaultVertexLabelRenderer(Color.lightGray));
        vv.getRenderContext().setEdgeDrawPaintTransformer(new ConstantTransformer(Color.lightGray));
        vv.getRenderContext().setEdgeStrokeTransformer(new ConstantTransformer(new BasicStroke(1.0f)));

        // customize the renderer
        // vv.getRenderer().setVertexRenderer(new MyGradientVertexRenderer<String, String>(Color.cyan, Color.white, true));
        vv.getRenderer().setVertexLabelRenderer(vlasr);

        vv.setGraphMouse(new DefaultModalGraphMouse());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an example on the Jung website [here](http://jung.sourceforge.net/applet/grapheditordemo.html) use `Editing` to add nodes and then switch to `Picking` to move the nodes you have added.  The sourcode is avalaible from [SourceFource](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jung/files/jung/) check out jung-samples-X.X.X.jar the class called GraphEditorDemo

[image]
Screen shot from the Jung Website

Comment: +1 & `accepted` for helping me get to the solution to my problem (see [my own answer for details](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21189059/2839597)).

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [GrahamA's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21184780/2839597), I found the code I was looking for:

```
    DefaultModalGraphMouse graphMouse = new DefaultModalGraphMouse();
    graphMouse.setMode(ModalGraphMouse.Mode.PICKING);
    vv.setGraphMouse(graphMouse);
```

That code changes the mode in `ModalGraphMouse` to the `PICKING`, which allows the user to select and move nodes around.